# How to show Drool rules into an Eclipse View

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, drools

Working environment: Drools 5.5.0.FINAL,JDK1.7

I'm developing an Eclipse Plugin which can analyse some Data with the help of Drools.
I already made an Eclipse View which should hold and show the loaded "Drools-rules".
Is there an elegant method to load some informations like rule-name?

Preparing a Rule-bean and fill it with information while processing the "then-clause" doesn't make me feel it's the right way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So the question is: Given a Drools file, how to get he names of the individual rules?

Comment: I found the AgendaEventListener which can be used to get the Information while firing rules...i would prefer to show the "loaded" rules before they will be fired.

@tobias_k Yes

Answer (score 1):

You can get rules from all knowledgePackages by accessing KnowledgeBuilder interface after adding resource.

e.g.

```
    KnowledgeBuilder knowledgeBuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory
            .newKnowledgeBuilder(knowledgeBuilderConfig);
    knowledgeBuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(ruleFile),
            ResourceType.DRL);

    Collection<KnowledgePackage> packages = knowledgeBuilder
            .getKnowledgePackages();
    for (KnowledgePackage knowledgePackage : packages) {
        for (Rule rule : knowledgePackage.getRules()) {
            System.out.println(rule.getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, that fits it. Thanks!